# React Native - Width of Child Relative to Parent Width

Tags: html, css, react-native

I have two buttons placed side by side within my `buttonWrapper`. I'm trying to make my two `button`s have the same width, with a small gap in between them.

For example, if the width of `buttonWrapper` is `300px`, we could have each button have a width of `145px` with a gap of `10px` in between them.

I tried to achieve this in various ways, using `width: 49%` as well as the following code:

```
export const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get("window").height;
export const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;
export const isPortrait = () => {
  const dim = Dimensions.get("screen");
  return dim.height >= dim.width;
};
```

to use the screen dimensions and then do something like `width: isPortrait() ? SCREEN_WIDTH : SCREEN_HEIGHT) * 0.7`,

however the problem is I don't want to the width of the `button` to be relative to the screen width, but instead to the width of the `buttonWrapper`

```
<View style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => OrderActionsHandler(item.id, 'complete')}
              style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: '#851631' }]}
            >
              <Text style={[styles.buttonText]}>
                {translations['Complete'][language]}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => setModalVisible()}
              style={styles.button}
            >
              <Text style={[styles.buttonText, { color: '#282A2A' }]}>
                {translations['Cancel'][language]}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>   


  const Styles = StyleSheet.create({buttonWrapper: {
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            alignItems: 'center',
            marginLeft: 25,
            marginRight: 25,
            marginTop: 10,
            display: 'flex',
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
          },
          button: {
            backgroundColor: '#CACBCD',
            paddingVertical: 7,
            borderRadius: 5,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }})
```

Answer (score 0):

Set flex: 1 to your buttonWrapper style.
Set width of button to the percent that you want:

```
width: "40%",
```

An other way (the one I am using) is to remove margin of your container than give it the width of the screen so

```
width: screen.width - marginLeft - marginRight - marginBetweenYourButton,
```

and in your button set the width to

```
width: (screen.width - marginLeft - marginRight - marginBetweenYourButton) / 2,
```